# How to request multiple queries within one string?

Tags: php, sql, boolean-logic

Im' not entirely sure I asked the correct question, but maybe if you see the code it might better explain what I'm trying to do.

So this query below listens for the post info from previous page:

```
<?php    
  if (isset($_REQUEST["water-selection"])
      || isset($_REQUEST["city-selection"])
      || isset($_REQUEST["bed-selection"])
      || isset($_REQUEST["bath-selection"])
      || isset($_REQUEST["keyword"])
      || isset($_REQUEST["price"])
      || isset($_REQUEST["pending"])){
    $where = " WHERE 1=1 ";
    if (isset($_REQUEST["water-selection"])
        && $_REQUEST["water-selection"]!="Water Selection"){
        if ($where != ""){ $where .= " AND ";}
        $where .= " field_RESIBDWR = '" . $_REQUEST["water-selection"] . "'";
    }
    if (isset($_REQUEST["city-selection"])
        && $_REQUEST["city-selection"]!="City Selection"){
        if ($where != ""){ $where .= " AND ";}
        $where .= " field_City = '" . $_REQUEST["city-selection"] . "'";
    }
    if (isset($_REQUEST["bed-selection"]) 
        && $_REQUEST["bed-selection"]!="Bed(s)"){
        if ($where != ""){ $where .= " AND ";}
        $where .= " field_Bedrooms >= '" . $_REQUEST["bed-selection"] . "'";
    }
    if (isset($_REQUEST["bath-selection"])
        && $_REQUEST["bath-selection"]!="Bath(s)"){
        if ($where != ""){ $where .= " AND ";}
        $where .= " field_Bathrooms >= '" . $_REQUEST["bath-selection"] . "'";
    }
    if (isset($_REQUEST["keyword"])){
        if ($where != ""){ $where .= " AND ";}
        $where .= " (field_city like '%" . $_REQUEST["keyword"] . "%'
        OR field_State like '%" . $_REQUEST["keyword"] . "%'
        OR field_ZipCode like '%" . $_REQUEST["keyword"] . "%'
        OR field_MLNumber like '%" . $_REQUEST["keyword"] . "%'
        OR field_RESIBDWR like '%" . $_REQUEST["keyword"] . "%'
        OR field_ListingOfficeName like '%" . $_REQUEST["keyword"] . "%'
        OR field_RESIADDI like '%" . $_REQUEST["keyword"] . "%'
        OR field_MarketingRemarks like '%" . $_REQUEST["keyword"] . "%'
        OR field_StreetNumber like '%" . $_REQUEST["keyword"] . "%'
        AND field_StreetDirection like '%" . $_REQUEST["keyword"] . "%'
        AND field_StreetName like '%" . $_REQUEST["keyword"] . "%'
        AND field_StreetSuffix like '%" . $_REQUEST["keyword"] . "%')";
    }
    if (isset($_REQUEST["price"])){
        $price = explode(";",urldecode($_REQUEST["price"]));
        if ($where != ""){ $where .= " AND ";}
        $where .= " field_ListingPrice between " . $price[0] . "
                  AND " . $price[1] . " ";
    }
    if (isset($_REQUEST["pending"])){
        if ($where != ""){ $where .= " AND ";}
        $where .= " field_Status = 'Pending'";
    }
  }
  else{
    $where = " WHERE `field_ZipCode` IN (SELECT zip FROM zipcodes)";
  }

  $sql = "SELECT count(id) as count FROM rc_Data $where";
  $res = mysql_query($sql,$con) or
         die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error() . "<br />\n$sql");

  $records_per_page = 10;

  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
    $total_rec = $row["count"]; 
  }

  $total_pages = ceil($total_rec / $records_per_page);

  $curr_page = 1;

  if (isset($_REQUEST["page"])){$curr_page=$_REQUEST["page"];}

  $start_index = ($curr_page-1) * $records_per_page; 
  if ($start_index  <0) {$start_index = 0;}
  //$sql = "SELECT *, round(3956 *2 * ASIN( SQRT( POWER( SIN( ( {$lati} - 
           field_Latitude ) * pi( ) /180 /2 ) , 2 ) + COS
           ( {$lati} * pi( ) /180 ) * COS( field_Latitude * pi( ) /180 ) *
           POWER( SIN( ( {$longi} - field_Longitude) * pi( ) /180 /2 ) ,
           2 ) ) ),0) AS distance FROM rc_Data order by distance,
           (`field_ListingAgentMLSID` = 'H10207') DESC,
           `field_ListingAgentMLSID`, field_ListingPrice DESC, id desc limit
           {$start_index}, {$records_per_page}";
  //$sql = "SELECT *, round(3956 *2 * ASIN( SQRT( POWER( SIN( ( {$lati} -
           field_Latitude ) * pi( ) /180 /2 ) , 2 ) + COS( {$lati} * pi( )
           /180 ) * COS( field_Latitude * pi( ) /180 ) * POWER( SIN( (
           {$longi} - field_Longitude) * pi( ) /180 /2 ) , 2 ) ) ),0) AS
           distance FROM rc_Data order by (`field_ListingAgentMLSID` =
           'H10207') DESC, `field_ListingAgentMLSID`, distance,
           field_ListingPrice DESC, id desc limit {$start_index},
           {$records_per_page}";
  $sql = "SELECT *, round(3956 *2 * ASIN( SQRT( POWER( SIN( ( {$lati} -
         field_Latitude ) * pi( ) /180 /2 ) , 2 ) + COS( {$lati} * pi( )
         /180 ) * COS( field_Latitude * pi( ) /180 ) * POWER( SIN( (
         {$longi} - field_Longitude) * pi( ) /180 /2 ) , 2 ) ) ),0) AS
         distance FROM rc_Data  $where order by (`field_ListingAgentMLSID`
         = 'H10207') DESC, field_ListingPrice DESC limit {$start_index},
         {$records_per_page}";
  $res = mysql_query($sql,$con) or
         die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error() . "<br />\n$sql");
  //echo $sql;

  unset($_GET['page']);
  $qs = http_build_query($_GET);
?>
```

The example the post url would look like:

```
[site]/listing.php?keyword="321+STREETNAME+STREETDirection+City+State&......
```

If I do things individually such as `"321"` it will search for `321` correctly, however, how can I get it to search `"321" + "Streetname" + City + State,` etc...

Hopefully that makes sense. I basically can't get it to search more than one match.

I was thinking possibly changing `OR` to `AND`, but then how will it separate other keywords?

Comment: 1) try adding final SQL statement you've constructed in some kind of output like print_r($where); and show us what you have there; 2) from your URL structure you should do an array explode("+", $_REQUEST["keyword"]) and then add it to your query

Comment: I've edited my original post. I was trying to basically add an address search inline with keyword search vs having to separate boxes on form page for just and address. If that makes sense, then that's where I got lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$where = '';

if (isset($_GET['keyword']) && '' !== trim($_GET['keyword'])) {
  $terms = explode(' ', $_GET['keyword']);
  $fields = array('city', 'state', 'zipcode');
  $criteria = array();
  foreach ($terms as $term) {
    if (!$term) continue;
    $term = @mysql_real_escape_string($term);
    $c = array();
    foreach ($fields as $field) {
      $c[] = 'field_'.$field.' LIKE \'%'.$term.'%\'';
    }

    $criteria[] = implode(' OR ', $c);
  }

  if ($criteria) {
    $condition = '('.implode(")\nAND (", $criteria).')';
    if ($where) $where .= ' AND ('.$condition.')';
    else $where = $condition;
  }
}

var_dump($where);
```

Please use escaping functions, or better, prepared statements to deal with SQL Injection issues. Also, this solution is far from optimal and you should consider restricting the fields that can be searched (for example with a dropdown list).

Comment: Ok I tried this. 

if (isset($_GET['keyword'])) {
  $terms = explode('+', $_GET['keyword']);
  $fields = array('ZipCode', 'MLNumber', 'RESIBDWR', 'ListingOfficeName', 'RESIADDI', 'MarketingRemarks', 'StreetNumber', 'StreetDirection', 'StreetName', 'StreetSuffix');
  $criteria = array();
  foreach ($terms as $term) {
    $term = mysql_real_escape_string($term);
    $c = array();
    foreach ($fields as $field) {
      $c[] = 'field_'.$field.' LIKE \'%'.$term.'%\'';
.....

didn't get error, but didn't get anything back.

Comment: Can you add a `var_dump($query)` statement before your `$res = ...` line?

Comment: Ok. I realized why there was nothing returned: $fields (needed to remove "s"). now I see the error: 

string(110) "SELECT count(id) as count FROM rc_Data WHERE 1=1 AND field_ListingPrice between 500000 AND 10000000 AND ()" Query failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1
SELECT count(id) as count FROM rc_Data WHERE 1=1 AND field_ListingPrice between 500000 AND 10000000 AND ()

Comment: I edited my answer, put that code in a php file and access it with `?keyword=a+b`, it should generate a valid where clause. Then integrate it back in your code.

Comment: string(9) "() AND ()" Query failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '() AND ()' at line 1
SELECT count(id) as count FROM rc_Data () AND ()

Comment: Problem is on your side, if you put that code all alone in a php file it works. Put your entire code on pastebin if you want me to have a look

Comment: http://pastebin.com/1DDGhrLg Replace your file with that one, I just copied back my code into it and it works

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [explode()](http://php.net//manual/pl/function.explode.php) function. You will get array of keywords.

```
$keywords = $_REQUEST["keyword"];
$arrayOfKeywords = explode('+', $keywords)
```

Comment: So are you saying replace the calls to each row and just plreadce with $arrayOfKeyords?

Comment: Yes. You can also pass array of elements by get method or you can use mod_rewrite or regular expression.

In mod_rewrite you can translate url:
`[site]/listing/key1/key2/key3...` into your version.

Try also to use PDO to connect with database.